# How to get yesterday date in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I want to get yesterday date from the current date in coldfusion.

```
<cfset yesterday = DateFormat(DateAdd('d',-7,Now()), 'mm/dd/yyyy')>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is good it should work.

```
<cfset yesterday = DateFormat(DateAdd('d',-1,Now()), 'mm/dd/yyyy')>
```